# to compare two string variables with one string variable as substring of other ignoring case

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
var haystack = " he she they you we yours us ALL OURS";

var needle = "he she ours";
```

I want to compare string needle and string haystack, ignoring case, for identifying if needle is a substring container of haystack.
Please suggest.

Comment: Are you truly finding a substring in a string, or do you want to find the words from t in list?

Comment: Represented the idea mentioned in the title to the question, in a more clearer way.

Answer (score 0):

> one string variable as a substring of other ignoring case

You can do this to ignore case

```
if (list.toLowerCase().indexOf(t.toLowerCase()) >= 0) { ... }
```

or

```
var regex = new RegExp(t, 'i'); // i = ignore case
if (regex.test(list)){ ... }
```

Comment: you might want to lower case `t` too - `t.toLowerCase()`

Comment: You're right. I was in the background focussing on the better regex version